# Jasmine + Webpack: vendor jasmine global functions

Tags: webpack, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm using Karma+Jasmine to test my webpack-based angular2 app.

To build project on development, I'm using `vendor.ts` for angular dependencies to keep main file as small as possible, and reduce webpack recompile time.

```
// Angular
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';
import '@angular/forms';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs';

import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

I've created `test.ts` in which I import all my tests. I recompile it every time before `karma start`.

The problem is that final `test.js` contains not only tests code, but the whole jasmine library. I want to vendor it too, but couldn't find right vendor import.

Looks like Jasmine is global library by default, and I haven't been able to find any `@types/jasmine-core` in dt.

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I was wrong in perceiving Jasmine as something I need to vendor. Functions like `describe` and `it` will be available on test run anyway, whether or not they will be present in the compiled files.

The only thing I needed to vendor in my case was `expect`, and I've achieved that through adding

```
import * as expect from "expect";
expect('true').toBe('true'); //doesn't work without it, for some reason
```

in the vendor file.